# parseSdkContent failed android

Tags: android, adt

I'm having this problem using eclipse android sdk on my mac.

```
parseSdkContent failed Source attachment path '\sdk\sources\android-15' for IClasspathEntry must be absolute
```

Check all my versions and are all updated, the directory of the SDK also is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's late, but I have got also this error and i think it can be helpfull for toher to handle a solution :

I have got this error

[image]

I have to create a new workspace and **import** all your project in your new workspace

[image]

Choose Android Studio Code into Workspace

[image]

Browse to your old workspace

[image]

Check your project to import

It's done !